# Benefits of using Identity Column instead of Unique Key

Tags: sql, database

I want to know the advantages of using the identity column on Unique Key. I have always used the identity column, and know it is better than Unique Key. But I want to know the benefits of Identity key over unique key.

Thanks

Comment: You know that it's better, but you don't know why?

Comment: @MrLister Yes... And I want to explain this to my client

Comment: They aren't really similar. An identity column is inherently unique, but it does not force uniqueness on any of your other columns so if you want column to be unique you should make it unique; if you add an identity column you could insert the same records in the other columns over and over and it would continue to give you uniqueness on the row while duplicating the rest of your information. Identity column incrementing can be turned on and off, you can change the current identity value to skip IDs. You can do all kinds of stuff.

Comment: I would say in the most general terms that a unique key would be used to enforce uniqueness on specific data columns while identity forces uniqueness at the row level regardless of the data.

Comment: Yes, in general we use identity (autoincrement) as primary key and avoid Name_of_product or any varchar/any other datatype for primary key.
The question is why we use identity for primary/foreign/... key...????

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to decide between using an identity column vs. a uniqueidentifier column as a primary key?

Uniqueidentifier (Guids) have the advantage of being unique across the entire environment, making it easier to uniquely identify a record outside of the context of a given table.  They also provide a key you can expose in your applications which are not easily iterated.

Identity columns use less storage and are therefore faster and more efficient.

There is no right answer for their use.  It really depends on the context.

Comment: Read Kimberly Tripp's excellent [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEYs and/or the clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/) blog post **before** using `GUID` as your clustering key ... at least in SQL Server, `GUID` is a **horribly bad choice** for your clustering key....

Answer (score -1):

A primary key can be used as a foreign key in another table, an identity column cannot.  Without seeing the type of data you are trying to store, I would recommend using an identity column but also setting that as your primary key.

Comment: In SQL Server, any table can reference the **primary key** or any **unique index**. So if you have a unique index on your `IDENTITY` column - it can **most definitely** be referenced from other tables!

Comment: foreign keys merely require a unique key in the parent table. IDENTITY is unrelated to a UNIQUE declaration

Comment: @Brain -- But only primary key has the benefit of using the varchar, so why just take the burden of using one more column.

Comment: You'd have to explain your schema design, maybe there is a purpose and maybe there isn't. If you want to relate the varchar value in that table to other tables then an identity column give you an int value you can use to make those joins instead of replicating a varchar all over the place.

Comment: Any column that's declared unique (more than one way to do that) can be the target of a foreign key reference in any SQL dbms that complies with SQL standards.